# Using a Boolean Expression in a StringBuilder

Tags: c#, string, syntax, boolean

I'm using a string builder to build some SQL Scripts.  I have a few Boolean Properties that I would like to test and then output different text based on true/false.  I've you the C# syntax below when assigning a value to a variable, but it isn't working for this particular situation.  Any ideas?

What I'm used to doing:

```
string someText = (dbInfo.IsIdentity) ? "First Option" : "Second Option";
```

Trying to duplicate the same thing inside a StringBuilder method, but this isn't working..

```
script.Append("sometext" + (dbInfo.IsIdentity) ? " IDENTITY(1,1)" : "");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add parentheses:

```
script.Append("sometext" + ((dbInfo.IsIdentity) ? " IDENTITY(1,1)" : ""));
```

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

```
script.Append( "sometext" );
script.Append( dbInfo.IsIdentity ? " IDENTITY(1,1)" : "" );
```

Answer (score 3):

Other from stating that if you have a stringbuilder you should use it to concatenate strings.

That said, the code bellow should work.

```
script.Append("sometext");
script.Append(dbInfo.IsIdentity ? " IDENTITY(1,1)" : "");
```

In this particular case you could also do:

```
script.Append("sometext");
if(dbInfo.IsIdentity) script.Append(" IDENTITY(1,1)");
```

Answer (score 3):

Extra parenthesis or even nicer use AppendFormat

```
script.AppendFormat("sometext{0}", dbInfo.IsIdentity ? " IDENTITY(1,1)" : "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a hunch but I think you need some more brackets:

```
script.Append("sometext" + ((dbInfo.IsIdentity) ? " IDENTITY(1,1)" : ""));
```

I would urge you to use a temporary variable for readability sake.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try wrapping the if/then/else in a set of parenthesis and see if that fixes the problem.  It may be a problem with the order in which that expression is being evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

A quick suggestion: if you're generating SQL like this, you may have a better time using a templating like [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) to generate it vs. using straight C#.